# What does "off" mean as in "He chose a three-star hotel off fashionable Orchard Road."

Tags: meaning

What does "off" mean as in "He chose a three-star hotel off fashionable Orchard Road."

As a foreigner, I was not sure. It seems to me that hotels are always "off the road", it's always "on the side of some road."

Does "off the road" mean it's near the road (off the road but on the side) or far away from the road?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

He chose a three-star hotel off fashionable Orchard Road.

If you look up the word "off" in a dictionary, you will find it's used in different senses.

In the OP's sentence, it has been used as a preposition in the sense of "near to/in the neighborhood of the fashionable Orchard Road", but not directly on it.